# Named Entity Recognition with entities split by other words

Tags: python, regex, nested, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a legal document where I want to automatically identify references to another legal document.

The documents are similarly structured like this dummy example:

> **Article 85 Paragraph 6 of Very Important Treaty No. 12/34/56** explicitly states you should do your research on **Another Important Treaty No. 56/78**, especially when it comes to **Article 1 Letter a** and **Article 2**.

My goal is to identify the references to other documents. At first I started with regex and that worked relatively well. However, as in the above example, I sometimes need to identify information based on the context. Thus, I am currently thinking to solve this issue with (nested) named entity recognition using spacy.

Now here is the problem: As stated I want to identify the links to other paragraphs of the same document or to paragraphs of other documents. In the above example, there are only links to external documents, namely these 3:

1. Article 85 Paragraph 6 of Very Important Treaty No. 12/34/56
2. Article 1 Letter a Another Important Treaty No. 56/78
3. Article 2 Another Important Treaty No. 56/78

Usually when labeling data for NER with spacy, you label the entities with a start index and end index and the corresponding entity type you want to identify. However, in this example the links I want to extract would actually be split across multiple sections, so it would actually require something like `start:ignore_start+_ignore_end:end`.

I thought about labeling the entities into `article`, `paragraph`, `letter` and `document_title`. However, then I would lack putting the information back together.

I stumbled across nested named entity recognition, but I am unsure if it really could help me. How would you think the data would have to be labeled in order to solve this problem?

EDIT: Regarding the expected output, I need to be able to tell, which document, article and paragraph I need to link to. So the expected output could for example be a list of dictionaries:

```
[
{
  'article': 85,
  'paragraph': 6,
  'letter': None,
  'document_title': 'Very Important Treaty No. 12/34/56'
},
{
  'article': 1,
  'paragraph': None,
  'letter': 'a',
  'document_title': 'Another Important Treaty No. 56/78'
},
{
  'article': 2,
  'paragraph': None,
  'letter': None,
  'document_title': 'Another Important Treaty No. 56/78'
}
]
```

I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

(before EDITs: It's no clear what exactly you need as the result: final text or dictionary/variable set (and, do you need `Letter` in output or not). )

Although, please consider this:

(EDIT: added some text for tests)

```
import re

def documents_identification(input_str):

    regex = r"(Article\s+(?P<article>\d+)(\s*|,|$))?" \
        + r"(Letter\s+(?P<letter>[a-z]+)(\s*|,|$))?" \
        + r"(Paragraph\s+(?P<paragraph>\d+)(\s*|,|$))?" \
        + r"(?:of\s)?(?P<document_title>(?<=\s)((Another|Very|Important|Treaty)\s+)+No\.\s+[\d/]+(?:\s*|\.|,|$))?"
    regex_flags = re.I + re.M + re.S

    # input_str += ' ' # sometimes simplier than "(?:\s*|,|$)" etc. at the end

    article = letter = paragraph = document_title = None # ''
    last = {} # ''
    article_paragraph_used = False

    result = []
    
    for m in re.finditer(regex, input_str, regex_flags):
        # if (m.groups() != (None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)):
        #     print(m.groups())
        if (m.group('document_title')):
            if (document_title and article_paragraph_used):
                article = letter = paragraph = None # ''
                article_paragraph_used = False # may be unnecessary
            document_title = m.group('document_title')
        if (m.group('article')):
            # article = "Article " + m.group('article') + ' '
            article = m.group('article')
            letter = None # ''
        if (m.group('letter')):
            # letter = "Letter " + m.group('letter') + ' '
            letter = m.group('letter')
        if (m.group('paragraph')):
            # paragraph = "Paragraph " + m.group('paragraph') + ' '
            paragraph = m.group('paragraph')
        
        # new = article + letter + paragraph + document_title
        new = {
            'article' : article,
            'paragraph' : paragraph,
            'letter' : letter,
            'document_title' : document_title
        }
        if (new!=last and document_title and article):
            article_paragraph_used = True
            last = new
            result += [new] # new + '\n'
    
    return result

str = 'Article 85 Paragraph 6 of Very Important Treaty No. 12/34/56 explicitly states you should do your research on Another Important Treaty No. 56/78, especially when it comes to Article 1 Letter a and Article 2.' \
    + ' Treaty No. 33/44/55 (VCLT), Article 4 of the VCLT contains a non-retroactivity clause, Article 19 is silent on the legal effect of impermissible reservations.' \
    + " The Union's aim is to promote peace, its values and the well-being of its peoples - in the Article 3 Paragraph 1 of Another Treaty No. 99/88." \
    + ' Treaty No. 66/77, Article 88 Letter b is important.' \

str = documents_identification(str)

print(str)
```

result:

```
[{'article': '85', 'paragraph': '6', 'letter': None, 'document_title': 'Very Important Treaty No. 12/34/56 '},
{'article': '1', 'paragraph': None, 'letter': 'a', 'document_title': 'Another Important Treaty No. 56/78'},
{'article': '2', 'paragraph': None, 'letter': None, 'document_title': 'Another Important Treaty No. 56/78'},
{'article': '4', 'paragraph': None, 'letter': None, 'document_title': 'Treaty No. 33/44/55 '},
{'article': '19', 'paragraph': None, 'letter': None, 'document_title': 'Treaty No. 33/44/55 '},
{'article': '3', 'paragraph': '1', 'letter': None, 'document_title': 'Another Treaty No. 99/88'},
{'article': '88', 'paragraph': None, 'letter': 'b', 'document_title': 'Treaty No. 66/77'}]
```

Comment: What is `article_paragraph_used` being used for? It can only be set to true once, which is why I am wondering.

Comment: You're right, I previously skipped necessary comment, edited later, look it now. That means, ````article_paragraph_used```` helps to avoid misuse new "Article xxx" with previous "... Treaty...", but it stricly depends on the order of occurrence "Article ... Treaty ...", ... " another Treaty" and its "Article ..." - like your example. Other examples might force major changes in code.

Comment: Hmm okay, yeah I had the same trouble with my regex as well. Which is why I was looking into NER, but I cannot wrap my head around how I would need to structure the training data so that I am able not only to extract the entities like <article>, <paragraph>, etc. but also to put those together that belong together.

Comment: On another note: I learned something regarding regex from your answer, which is why I upvoted it, however, it is not exactly what I am looking for, as it only works specifically in this example and would cause issues if applied to an actual legal document. I am wondering if I could reset the article_paragraph_used flag somehow. In my case, I also have self-references within one document, e.g. "For further information, see Article 4". In that case, the treaty is not mentioned, but the reader knows that this document is meant and not a different document.

Comment: Yes, I know there may be a lot of cases in documents. But regex(es) have to fit them exactly. The last one was only due to example you've given. So, better give more examples, I think them might be the only chance to type them into regex(es) correctly.